# Unpickle of a pipeline fail on AWS Lambda

Tags: python, scikit-learn, aws-lambda, pickle, xgboost

First, sorry if the solution is already published, I have looked at so many posts and did not find a way to work this out

I have a Python class that works fine on my machine, in order to TRAIN + RUN a ML model.

I want to perform the RUN (and only the run) on AWS Lambda, but it fail during the pickle.load as it seems to not find the transformations functions used by the pipeline (while they are available in the code)

> "Can't get attribute 'myMLClass' on <module '**main**' from
> '/var/runtime/awslambda/bootstrap.py'>", "errorType": "AttributeError"

Code is in Python 3.6, it use an sklearn pipeline, with XGBOOST, and Pickle to save/load the model.

Here is an overview of it:

```
import stuff

class myMLClass:

    def myTransformation(self, dataframe): 
        #myTransformations

    def train_model(self)
        preprocessor = FunctionTransformer(myTransformation, validate=False)
        xgb = XGBClassifier()
        pipeline_xgb = make_pipeline(preprocessor, xgb)
        #[XGB Stuff: fit, predict,...]
        with open("myTrainedPipeline.pkl", 'wb') as file:
            pickle.dump(pipeline_xgb, file)

    def run_model(self)
        with open("myTrainedPipeline.pkl", 'rb') as file:
            pipeline = pickle.load(file)    ==> Which trigger the error

def main():
    myObject = myMLClass("DEV")
    myObject.run_model()
```

Again, the same class works fine on my machine for both training and running. I understand Pickle does not serialize the transformation functions but only a reference to it, this is why I included the both training & runnning operations under the same class

**Note:** issue is the same if I try to unpickle from the main() function

Thanks a lot for your help!

Alex

Comment: FYI I had been able to tackle this issue thanks to the explanations from this page:

https://www.stefaanlippens.net/python-pickling-and-dealing-with-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-thing.html

Basically, I needed to split the main and the module in 2 different files. 

I believe this is because of the way AWS Lambda works, especially the bootstrap.py. As soon as I split the files and added the import module to the main file, It was explicit for the proxy that it needs to import it, so it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI I had been able to tackle this issue thanks to the explanations from this page:

https://www.stefaanlippens.net/python-pickling-and-dealing-with-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-thing.html

Basically, I needed to split the main and the module in 2 different files.

I believe this is because of the way AWS Lambda works, especially the bootstrap.py. After the split, it was explicit for the proxy that it needs to import the dedicated module, as the import was declared in the main